# Mute only the running apps sound in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which there is some speech to the user. there is also a mute button. Can i mute the sound of my application alone, not affecting the sound of music player if it is playing in the back ground??

Comment: I would like to know how you are playing the sound for your application, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
 mp.start();
```

for Mute

```
mp.setvolume(0,0);
```

& Unmute or full volume

```
mp.setvolume(0,1);
```