# how to check mobile in Mute And Offline mode in android?

Tags: android

Hi all i need to check phone mode whether it is in Mute mode or Offline mode .

My task is if phone in mute state then i have to do task1

if phone in offline state then i have to do task2

so how we can check how to check mute or offline mode?

thanks in advance

Comment: see this 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529237/mute-only-the-running-apps-sound-in-android/9529310#9529310[enter link description here][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AudioManager is an api I think of interest of you, use its method getMode and getStreamVolume:

AudioManager provides access to volume and ringer mode control.

Use Context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) to get an instance of this class.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can be helpful....

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Activity.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    switch(audioManager.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        System.out.println("Normal Mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        System.out.println("Silent Mode");
        break;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya following code is working for me

```
AudioManager ab=(AudioManager) ServiceCall.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int ring_valume=ab.getRingerMode();
```

verify this [The ringer modes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getRingerMode%28%29)